# Can't return os family using ansible_os_family

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-esx, ansible, ansible-playbook

I am trying to get the OS family of my host machine using ansible. This is the command I use.

```
ansible my-host -i hosts.ini -m setup | grep ansible_os_family
```

This is what my host file looks like.

```
[my-host] myhostvm.com  ansible_ssh_pass=mypw ansible_ssh_user=root
```

I however get this message:

> "ansible_os_family": "NA",

I try to run this as well.

```
ansible my-host -i hosts.ini -m setup | grep ansible_distribution
```

This is the result:

> "ansible_distribution": "NA",  "ansible_distribution_major_version":
>   "NA",  "ansible_distribution_release": "NA", 
>   "ansible_distribution_version": "NA",

Can someone explain to me why it doesn't return any OS family?

Answer (score 3):

The Ansible code to get the value for `ansible_os_family` is in [lib/ansible/module_utils/facts.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/facts.py#L609).

If the os family of the target system is not contained in the `OS_FAMILY` list you will need to patch the Ansible code to add your os family. Currently the list contains:

```
OS_FAMILY = dict(
    RedHat = 'RedHat', Fedora = 'RedHat', CentOS = 'RedHat', Scientific = 'RedHat',
    SLC = 'RedHat', Ascendos = 'RedHat', CloudLinux = 'RedHat', PSBM = 'RedHat',
    OracleLinux = 'RedHat', OVS = 'RedHat', OEL = 'RedHat', Amazon = 'RedHat',
    XenServer = 'RedHat', Ubuntu = 'Debian', Debian = 'Debian', Raspbian = 'Debian', Slackware = 'Slackware', SLES = 'Suse',
    SLED = 'Suse', openSUSE = 'Suse', SuSE = 'Suse', SLES_SAP = 'Suse', Gentoo = 'Gentoo', Funtoo = 'Gentoo',
    Archlinux = 'Archlinux', Manjaro = 'Archlinux', Mandriva = 'Mandrake', Mandrake = 'Mandrake', Altlinux = 'Altlinux',
    Solaris = 'Solaris', Nexenta = 'Solaris', OmniOS = 'Solaris', OpenIndiana = 'Solaris',
    SmartOS = 'Solaris', AIX = 'AIX', Alpine = 'Alpine', MacOSX = 'Darwin', FreeBSD = 'FreeBSD', HPUX = 'HP-UX', openSUSE_Leap = 'Suse'
```

Ansible checks for `/etc/$OS-release` to determine the os. If the OS family of your target system is in the `OS_FAMILY` list you should check if the `/etc/$OS-release` is correct.